# i want to return two different response when mocking promise method

Tags: reactjs, promise, mocking, jestjs

I have a promise method, inside that i have if condition. when i mock this promise method. i can able to return one value only. i am not able to cover both the condition. Can someone please help me on this.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import myLogs from '../service/myLogs';

export class MyMainComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.getLogs();
  }

  getLogs() {
    myLogs(5).then((logList) => {
        if(logList.length > 0 ) {
            // need to cover this.
        } else {
            // need to cover this.
        }
    });
  }

  render() { return null; }
}
```

service/myLogs.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const myLogs = (loglength) => {
    return axios.get("url).then((response) =>{return response})
}
export default myLogs
```

service/**mocks**/myLogs.js

```
const mockValue = [];
const mockValues = ["1", "2"];

const myLogs = (loglength) => {
// if i return "mockValue" then its covering else part. 
// if i return "mockValues" then its covering if part.
// But i want to cover both. how can i mock to cover both.
    return Promise.resolve(mockValue)
}
export default myLogs
```

test/MyMainComponent.js

```
jest.mock(../service/myLogs.js
// some other code..
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use your parameter `loglength` to create an array with your desired length.

Like this:

```
const mockValue = (length) => Array(length).fill(3)
...
const myLogs = (loglength) => {
    return Promise.resolve(mockValue(loglength))
}
export default myLogs
```

So here you can specify how many logs do you want on each test case :)